# What's so special about MPI that makes it preferred to Server/Clients Model?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I'm trying to wrap my head around MPI. It seems like it's the de-facto model for parallel scientific computing. However, I can't see what makes it so special that it's being preferred over, say, the Server/Clients model with JSON or xml?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed, MPI is the de-facto standard for (distributed memory) parallel scientific computing. One can only speculate why that is so. A few reasons:

- MPI is an API standard, it doesn't specify any wire protocol, leaving any such low-level details to the implementation. (Indeed, hypothetically a MPI implementation could use JSON or XML and conform to the standard, although I'm pretty sure performance would be awful compared the current real implementations that to the best of my knowledge use an efficient binary protocol.) This allows the implementation freedom to implement MPI as efficiently as possible on a wide variety of network hardware architectures, providing "performance portability" to applications. This is important, as large applications tend to have lifetimes significantly longer than the ~5 years of a typical supercomputer.
- MPI is NOT a client-server model, although it's flexible enough to allow the user to implement such a communication scheme if the user so wishes. Client-server models tend to suffer from scalability limitations, and instead large-scale MPI applications tend to use a symmetric processing model where all ranks are (almost) equal.
- MPI provides a large variety of communication patterns used in scientific applications. E.g. collective operations such as broadcasts, reductions, scatter/gather etc. Again, since MPI is an API standard and does not specify a wire protocol, the MPI implementation has a lot of freedom to implement these operations in an efficient manner for any particular network hardware and topology.